# How to move the mouse pointer to the center of the screen and apply left click?

Tags: google-chrome, batch-file, vbscript, windows-8.1

I have a Kiosk with Google Chrome browser running on boot. But when it boots it does not work unless left click is generated on the center (because of Google Chrome bug). I tried following but its not working.

how to tell go to center of the screen and click left (not right click).

```
Set WshShell = wscript.createobject("Wscript.Shell") 
WshShell.SendKeys("+{F10}")
```

EDIT: `runme.bat`

```
timeout 10 > nul
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --kiosk
```

EDIT: `centerme.vbs` (failed)

```
set a = createobject("wscript.shell")
Private Declare Function SetCursorPos Lib "user32" (ByVal x As Long, ByVal y As Long) As Long

Private Sub someSub()
  dim someX as Long, someY as Long
  someX = 400
  someY = 400
  SetCursorPos someX, someY
End Sub

wscript.quit
```

Comment: Which CLI did you use to launch chrome in Kiosk mode ? or can you provide us the code source to launch it in this mode ?

Comment: See my EDIT section, that is how its executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VBScript doesn't allow for moving the mouse cursor or applying mouse clicks. The "VBScript" code you posted is VB/VBA code and will not work in VBScript. You need something like [AutoIt](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) for what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

And if you try like this ?

```
Option Explicit
Dim ws
set ws = CreateObject("wscript.shell")
wscript.sleep 10000
ws.run "chrome.exe --kiosk"
```

Comment: Same problem. after your line 5. How can you now make a mouse left click on the chrome.exe? then the problem will be solved else the problem still exist.

Comment: How to use this? its not working ` Dim Shell : Set Shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
Shell.Run"RunDll32.exe user32.dll,SetCursorPos 400,400"`

Comment: Can you execute those after line 5? e.g: http://www.rgagnon.com/pbdetails/pb-0204.html

Comment: When i execute this then i can open controle panel but the SetCursorPos line is not working ? ` Dim Shell : Set Shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
Shell.Run "rundll32 shell32,Control_RunDLL"
Shell.Run"RunDll32.exe user32.dll,SetCursorPos 400,400" `

Answer (score 0):

I had this "left-click" problem myself yesterday.
The solution is to enable the Windows "Mouse Keys" feature so that you can not only move the mouse cursor around but also left-click:

```
set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
```

'Enable Mouse Keys

```
WshShell.SendKeys "{%}{+}{NUMLOCK}"
WScript.Sleep 500
```

'To confirm the enable

```
WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
WScript.Sleep 500
```

'Left-click in Windows 10

```
WshShell.SendKeys "{\}"
```

'Left-click in Windows 7

```
WshShell.SendKeys "{Pad5}" (might also be just, "{5}" )
```